# Ruby: undefined method `delete', deleting parent and child data at the same time

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie programmer, basically I'm trying to delete a record from a database table, however this record would be used on a child table with a composed primary key taking both from different tables.

This is the class of the table I need to delete the child data from.

```
class Detalle_Mapa 
  include DataMapper::Resource
  storage_names[:default] = 'detalle_ma'

  property :clave_mapa, String, :length => 2, :required => true, :key => true
  property :clave_asig, String, :length => 10, :required => true, :key => true
  property :clave_cuatri, String, :length => 2, :required => true

  belongs_to :mapa_curricular, 'Mapa_Curricular', :child_key => [:clave_mapa], :key => true
  belongs_to :cuatrimestre, 'Cuatrimestre', :child_key => [:clave_cuatri], :key => true
  belongs_to :asignatura, 'Asignatura', :child_key => [:clave_asig]

end
```

So now when I try to delete data from the parent table, it won't delete it since the PK is being used on the child table for other data. If this was normal SQL sintax it wouldn't be a big deal but I'm having a hard time finding a way around it on Ruby.

This is the basic method that works when deleting data that's not being used as a FK.

```
delete '/deleteMapCurricular/:clave_mapa' do
  @mapa = Mapa_Curricular.get(params[:clave_mapa])
  if @mapa      
     @mapa.destroy
     redirect '/catMapCurricular'
  end    
end
```

And this is one of the ways I've tried to delete the child data, which is clearly not right...

```
     Detalle_Mapa.where(:clave_mapa => [params[:clave_mapa]]).delete_all
```

Is there an easy way to just delete a bunch of data from a database that I'm not aware of? Or what I'm I not getting about this ActiveRecords on Ruby?
I'm sorry if the question is ambiguous or if I'm not explaining myself clearly, I usually find everything on forums and there is no need to ask myself. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If I understand it clearly, when you want parent to delete, you want children associated with parent also to be deleted?

Comment: Yes, I need to delete everything all together

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not giving out the exact answer. But I can tell a concept in this answer

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fruits, dependent: :destroy
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So in the above example, if you delete a user, the associated fruits for that user will also be deleted automatically.

Comment: Is ActiveRecord a new gem I would need to install because none of my classes use it and it's giving me the error "unitialized constant ActiveRecord".   And if I remove that part it throws ":dependent does not map to a property or relationship in... "  Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Are you using rails?

Comment: Sorry my answer is no longer applicable. My answer is rails specific